# Import-Module inside a function, and made it avaible in the all script

Tags: powershell, scope, import-module

I have this:

```
function ImportModule(){
    Import-module -Name .\Out-IniFile.ps1 -Force -Verbose -Global
    Out-IniFile

}
ImportModule
Out-IniFile
```

In my Out-IniFile.ps1 i have this:

```
Function Out-IniFile {
blah
blah
...
}
```

Why "Out-IniFile" works inside my function and trow me :

```
Out-IniFile : The term 'Out-IniFile' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,...
```

outside of it ? I don't get it I mentionned -Global , though.

Comment: Maybe [Export-ModuleMember](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/export-modulemember?view=powershell-6) will be helpful for your situation.

Comment: try using `-scope global`, instead. The default is to import into the `local` scope.

Comment: same with `Export-ModuleMember` and  Export-ModuleMember I tried (i put it in place of `ImportModule` --> `Export-ModuleMember -Function ImportModule` but it gave me `Export-ModuleMember : The Export-ModuleMember cmdlet can only be called from inside a module.`

Comment: @Martin Maybe refactor your script into an actual module instead?

Comment: I meant same with `-scope global` of course at my previous answer. Nevermind, just rename "Out-IniFile.ps1" to "Out-IniFile.psm1" worked...Little bit disappointed it was this actually lol. Thank you guys !!